# since there's a delete an answer option on stack overflow, why isn't there an appears to be solved also?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I received an odd response on stack overflow until someone explained it to me, so instead of the delete option, why can't there be an appears to solve the problem option?

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589111/what-text-editor-would-you-recommend-for-my-web-page for an example of what I mean.

Comment: Why would we keep that post around?  It's off-topic anyway.  The way questions get marked SOLVED is by the OP accepting the correct answer (by clicking the checkmark next to the correct answer).

Comment: If anything, an "appears to be solved" sounds like an option to use for a long-standing question with good answers but no accepted answer... particularly when the asker is a 1-rep hit-and-runner and leaves the question open forever.

Comment: @nhgrif That's the goal.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert Harvey mentioned the only "appears to be solved" indicator is the green check mark, but I don't think that's what you were asking about...

In the Low Quality Review the interface looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the options provided are Looks Good, Edit, Recommend Deletion, and Skip
And the guidance for choosing between these options is:

> - Looks OK if nothing is wrong with this answer
> - Edit if you can fix all the problems with this answer
> - Recommend Deletion to recommend that this answer be deleted
> - Skip if you are not sure and want to go to the next item

I'm guessing given our exchange in the comments under your answer that you would have preferred me to choose "Looks OK", but given the style of [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24589326/1947286), the appropriate action was "Recommend Deletion".

After clicking "Recommend Deletion" this dialog pops up, giving reviewers the option to leave a comment

[image]

The whole point of this process is to give users a chance to improve their posts before they get deleted and to offer some guidance on what's wrong with their posts so they hopefully don't repeat the mistake in the future.